# How to Check if the the user has uploaded a file or not in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

I have created a form in which I have 2 text fields and one File field. I have added Javascript on `'text'` fields. If user left `'text'` fields and press submit button, `All Fields are Required`Font turns red, I want to turn it red as well when user doesn't upload any Image. I have tried various ways but its not working. Kindly tell me the way of doing it.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction()
{
    var category_name   =   document.forms["insert"]["sub_category_name"].value;
    //var image =           document.forms["insert"]["file"].item();

    var error           =   document.getElementById("error");


    if(category_name=="" )
    {
        error.style.color="Red";
        return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //message.innerHTML="Data Inserted!";
            }
    }


</script>
```

PHP code

```
    <?php

echo "
    <form name='insert' action='sub_categories.php' method='POST' onSubmit='return myFunction()' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <table class='gridtable' border=2 bordercolor='#CCCCCC' cellpadding='10'>
        <tr>
        <th>
            Sub-Category Name: </th><td>    <input type='text' name='sub_category_name' ></td></tr>";





            echo "
        <tr>
        <th>
            Image1:</th><td> <input type='file' name= 'file' ></td></tr> 

            ";
```

Thanks

Comment: also try `value` : `document.forms["insert"]["file"].value`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just get your file input by id and check if it's value is empty :

```
if(document.getElementById('file').value=='') {//something here }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best, easiest bet is to use JQuery as follows:

```
$("input[type='file'][name='file']").filter(function (){
    return !this.value
}).length;
```

The reason you cannot use ':empty' is because ':empty' matches when an element does not have any descendants. Input elements cannot have descendants, thus your 'input' will always evaluate ':empty' as true.

Comment: he is not using jQuery